# Jenkinsfile parallel stages - how to stop pipeline immediately if stage one fails but continue if the second fails

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-plugins

below example of a jenkinsfile pipeline using parallel stages.
i would like to abort the pipeline immediately  if stage number one fails, but continue if stage number two fails.
using failfast is not good because it will fail no matter of the stage that fails.
any idea ?

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            stages{
                stage('parallel')
                {
                    parallel {
                        stage('1'){
                            steps{
                                echo '1'
                            }
                        }
                        stage('2'){
                            steps{
                                echo '2'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

tried using catchError but couldnt solve this

Answer (score 0):

There is a failFast option in jenkins. Official docu can be found in example 26 of the this [jenkins docu page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel)
You can try something like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any
options {
    parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
}
stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            stages{
                stage('parallel')
                {
                    parallel {
                        stage('1'){
                            steps{
                                echo '1'
                            }
                        }
                        stage('2'){
                            steps{
                                echo '2'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```